# Issue for SUM all data with NULL in JTable

Tags: java, swing, null, sum, jtable

I am using Java.
I have various data in a `JTable`.
I wish to SUM all but there contain NULL.

```
float sum_OverTime_C = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < jTable_3.getRowCount(); i++) {
    sum_OverTime_C = sum_OverTime_C + Float.parseFloat(jTable_3.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
}
jLabel_Total_OverTime.setText(Float.toString(sum_OverTime_C));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the value is `null` or not before summing, for example :

```
if(jTable_3.getValueAt(i, 1) != null){ 
   sum_OverTime_C += Float.parseFloat(jTable_3.getValueAt(i, 1).toString());
}
```

Comment: there are lot of data. most of the data are NULL.
there any idea beside this idea(validation) ? Please..

Comment: @ArthurTan there are no way to do what you want, except checking the field